# How can I apply css style in props in React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

In this code `{index}` is a list number, and I want to apply styles only value of `{index}` between 1 and 3. I'm a beginner of coding, would you help me? Thanks.

```
 _renderRankings=()=>{
  const movies= this.state.movies.map((movie, i)=>{
    console.log(movie)
      return  <L_Ranking
      title={movie.title_english}
      key={movie.id}
      genres={movie.genres}
      index={i}
      />
  })
  return movies
}
```

---

```
function L_Ranking({title, genres, index}){
  return (
    <div className="L_Ranking">
      <span className="L_Ranking_Number"> {index+1}</span>
      <span className="L_Ranking__Column">
        {title}
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an empty `style` object and add your styles to it if the index is in your desired range:

```
function L_Ranking({title, genres, index}){
  const style = {};

  if (index >= 1 && index <= 3) {
    style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }

  return (
     <div className="L_Ranking" style={style}>
       <span className="L_Ranking_Number">{index+1}</span>
       <span className="L_Ranking__Column">
       {title}
       </span>
     </div>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally render class styles -

```
<span className={index >= 1 && index <= 3 ? 'L_Ranking_Number' : '' } >
```

`L_Ranking_Number` will only be applied when `index` is inclusive `1-3`.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully you don't actually need to use JavaScript to conditionally apply css here, instead you can use a css nth-child selector on the parent class.

An nth-child selector takes a formula to decide which children to apply it's styles to. For example to apply css to every child from the second child upwards for HTML structured this way:

```
<div className="parent-class">
    <div />
    <div />
    <div />
</div
```

You could use this css

```
.parent-class:nth-child(n + 2) {
    background-color: papayawhip;
}
```

For your case where you need a range, you can use this css on your parent class similarly

```
.parent-class:nth-child(n + 2):nth-child(-n + 4) {
    // your css
}
```

[Here](http://nthmaster.com) is good site for you to read about nth-child selectors if you are interested.